# Is Apple Metal triangle rasterisation rule top-left?

Tags: ios, metal, rasterizing

Does Metal use the "top-left rule" to decide whether a pixel center that is exactly on a triangle edge is considered inside the triangle? Or what is the rule used?

Thank you for help!